# SF System Status page - how to see entries older than 33 days?

Tags: trust

Where can I see this data that is older than 33 days?

More specifically, I need to know if there were any issues with NA13 instance on 3/25/14 at 2:30 PM EST, but the oldest data this site is showing today is for April 4 2014.

http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/status

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to find it in the RSS feed. For example, the [RSS feed for NA13](http://trust.salesforce.com/rest/rss/NA13) goes back to March 11.

Looks like there was an issue close to your date around email:

```
<item>
<title>
Alert: [ AP0 AP1 EU0 (EMEA) EU1 EU2 EU3 NA0 (SSL) NA1 NA2 NA3 NA4 NA5 NA6 NA7 NA8 NA9 NA10 NA11 NA12 NA13 NA14 NA15 NA16 CS1 CS2 CS3 CS4 CS5 CS6 CS7 CS8 CS9 CS10 CS11 CS12 CS13 CS14 CS15 CS16 CS17 CS18 CS19 CS20 CS30 ] On March 26, 2014, the salesforce.com Technology Team observed a performance degradation affecting inbound email services for the Salesforce application. The problem began on March 26, 2014 at 13:50 UTC and was resolved by 17:30 UTC. During this time, a subset of customers may have experienced intermittent inability to send email into the Salesforce application. Inbound email messages affected by this issue were returned to the sending address and will not be delivered. Thank you for your continued business and patience during this situation.
</title>
<link>http://trust.salesforce.com/trust/status</link>
<guid isPermaLink="false">NA13 - Alert - 2014-03-26 13:50:00.0</guid>
<description>
The problem was caused by a procedural error during configuration and testing of new instances which are not yet live. The state of the new instances affected the ability for inbound email requests to be successfully routed to the appropriate instance. This caused a subset of inbound email requests to not be delivered and returned to the sending address. Action was taken to prevent further email to be handled by the new instances and normal functionality was restored.

 Actions to Prevent Future Incidents:
 The salesforce.com Technology Team -
 - Is reviewing new instance configuration and testing procedures to identify how the procedural error occurred
 - Will implement appropriate safeguards to prevent a similar error in the future
</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 26 Mar 2014 13:50:00 +0000</pubDate>
</item>
```